# TS define type of dynamic attribute in an returning object

Tags: typescript

So I'm getting this kind of data from an API.

```
{
   data: {
     [dynamicPropertyName]: { // property name changes depending on endpoint 
       elements: [], // this also dynamically change depending on the endpoint
       total: 0
     }
   }
}
```

now I figured a way how to solve having dynamic properties in the data property, although I can't seem to pass the correct type to `elements` property.

```
export interface Result<T> {
  elements: T[];
  total: number;
}

export type SearchResultData< T > = {
  [ k in keyof T ]: Result<T>
};

export interface SearchResult<T> {
  data: SearchResultData<T>;
}


interface User {
  name: string;
}

export interface UsersResult {
  users: User[]
}

export type UsersSearchResult = SearchResult<UsersResult>

const a: UsersSearchResult = {
  data: {
    users: {
      elements: [{
        /// here it's resolving the UserResult Type instead of User
      }],
      total: 0
    }
  }
}
```

I want to avoid defining the User type twice, like `export type UsersSearchResult = SearchResult<UsersResult, USer>`.

Is there any way I could extract the type from `T[k]` I'm passing to `SearchResult<T>`?

something like

```
export type SearchResultData< T > = {
      [ k in keyof T ]: Result<T[k]> /// ????
    };
```

**UPDATE:**

Turned out to be just my silly mistake. Just for anyone else hitting the same issue. Here is the updated code.

```
export interface Result<T> {
  elements: T;
  total: number;
}

export type SearchResultData< T > = {
  [ k in keyof T ]: Result<T[k]>
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that `elements` are going to be the object belong to the *same* key. Like below, I just made elements to be the value of the key that `k` represents.

(Also, it was a little difficult for me to look up and down across multiple types so, I created one unified interface, but it should work with your code too).

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/KwXG8W)

```ts
export interface SearchResult<T> {
  data: {
    [k in keyof T]: {
      elements: T[k];
      total: number;
    };
  };
}

// Example
interface User {
  name: string;
}

export interface UsersResult {
  users: User[];
}

export type UsersSearchResult = SearchResult<UsersResult>;

const a: UsersSearchResult = {
  data: {
    users: {
      elements: [
        {
          name: "wwe",
        },
        {
          name: "wwe",
        },
      ],
      total: 0,
    },
  },
};
```